autostarting a chromium webpage kiosk mode
i'm using autostar to autostart a webpage and a python code on boot and it works perfectly  until i include kiosk mode ,it seems to have a problem with the screen resolution which makes the webpage open but not visible it dosen't work unless i unplug the hdmi from the display and replug it ,is there any resolution configuration i can do to solve this problem. 'note: even if i try to run the webpage open command <chromium-browser https://www.elhelbsmart.com --kiosk> in terminal it still gives the same problem'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
